# django datetime fromisoformat: argument must be str error

Tags: python, django, web

I'm trying to save the date information to the database but I'm getting a type error:

```py
def message_send(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.user.username
            email = request.user.get_email
            title = request.POST.get('title')
            message = request.POST.get('message')
            date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
            support = supportmessages(name=name,email=email,title=title,message=message,date=date)
            support.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your mesaage has been sent')
            return render(request,"messagesend.html")
        return render(request,"messagesend.html")
    else:
        return redirect(request,"{% url 'home' %}")
```

The code's in this `views.py` file I try `timezone.now` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line:

```py
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

You are actually feeding the `date` field the `django.db.models.DateTimeField` [class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#quick-example) that is used to define the database field.

You should replace it with the value you want to insert:

```py
date = timezone.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving datetime value, so it gives error.
First import timezone from django utils

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

and replace

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

to

```
date = timezone.now()
```